# How to limit the touch events to only one view controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am making something similar to ruzzle and in order to slide between the letters (buttons) i am using touch events (`touchBegan`, `touchMove`, `touchEnded`).

The application consists of two `view controllers` in one `storyboard`. The fist one is for the main menu and the second for inGame screen and i switch between them by using the `storyboard` id. Everything works perfectly fine until you switch from the inGame view to the MainMenu view.

The problem is when you return to the main menu from the inGame screen, the touch events are still active and this is an issue, because when you touch anywhere on the screen the app crashes. This happens, because the methods in the inGame view are called from the MainMenu view for some reason. Is there anyway to limit the touch events only for the inGameView?

PS. The `setUserInteraction:(BOOL)` method is not an option in my case, because you cannot press the buttons in the main menu anymore.

Moving from the MainMenu to inGame with

```
GamePlayView *gpv = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GamePlayView"];
[self presentViewController:gpv animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And from the inGame to MainMenu with

```
ViewController *svc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
[self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Show code for how you move between the view controllers.

Comment: I am moving from the MainMenu to inGame with                 `GamePlayView *gpv = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GamePlayView"];
    [self presentViewController:gpv animated:YES completion:nil];`      and from the inGame to MainMenu with `ViewController *svc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that each time you `presentViewController:animated:completion:` the previous view controller still exists 'under' the new view controller. If your top presented view controller isn't handling / blocking all touches then they will be passed on to other views / controllers in the responder chain.

From the main view you could continue to use `presentViewController:animated:completion:`. But to get from the game view back to the menu you should use `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`
. This will remove the game view controller from the screen (and destroy the instance) so it doesn't continue to take up resources or handle touches.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem is related to touch events. Each time you switch view controllers you're creating a new view controller. Seems more likely that when you move from the game to the menu you should simply dismiss the game controller, allowing the existing main controller to be displayed again.